# Python: Transpose over the secondary diagonal

Tags: python, python-2.7, transpose

If I have this matrix, for example:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
          [5, 6, 7, 8], 
          [9, 10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

And I want to transpose it over the secondary diagonal, without touching the first row and first column. It would look like this:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
          [5, 16, 12, 8], 
          [9, 15, 11, 7],
          [13, 14, 10, 6]]
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't change the matrix:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        temp = copy.deepcopy(matrix[i][j])
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[4-j][4-i]
        matrix[4-j][4-i] = temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are swapping TWO times each pair of variables, building again the same matrix.

Also, you don't need the `copy.deepcopy` call for a matrix of integers, and you reference a `table` variable which is undefined

```
# Working code
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4 - i):
        matrix[i][j], matrix[4 - j][4 - i] = matrix[4 - j][4 - i], matrix[i][j]
```

Comment: You could simplify it a bit by using `for j in range(1, 4-i)`. Also, you can get rid of the `temp` variable by using tuple unpacking `a, b = b, a`.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote this a bit fast. `for (i in range(10)): if i < 5: ` was a bit dumb :). I corrected the post

Comment: @Eloims what would the range be for transposing over the main diagonal?

Comment: `i in range(1, 4)` and `j in range(1, i)` if you keep the strange condition of not touching the first column and row. Are you doing homework?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does't work because you are swapping the items two times: swapping `matrix[i][j]` with `matrix[4-i][4-j]` with both `i` and `j` in `[1, 2, 3]` means that you swap:

- `[1][1]` with `[3][3]`
- `[1][2]` with `[3][2]`
- ...
- again `[3][2]` with `[1][2]`
- again `[3][3]` with `[1][1]`

You can clearly see that you swap each item two times, which brings you back to the original matrix. To fix this you can simply use `range(1, 3)` instead.

Also, you can swap the values inline, you don't need to use `copy`and a temporary variable. Here'a a working example:

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    for j in range(1, 3):
        matrix[i][j], matrix[4-j][4-i] = matrix[4-j][4-i], matrix[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider converting your `list` to an array-like object such as `np.matrix` to take advantage of standard 2D operations. For example:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8],
      [9, 10, 11, 12],
      [13, 14, 15, 16]])

matrix[1:,1:]=matrix[1:,1:][::-1].transpose()[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
          [5, 6, 7, 8], 
          [9, 10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15, 16]]
subflipped = matrix
subflipped [1:,1:] = np.flip(matrix[1:,1:])
subflipped
```